# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

I have no idea what's happening. All these errors coming up, here's the pic.

[image: Code Image]

I imported a project from github and all these errors are here, not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Build->Clear Project and make sure you have appropriate dependency in your gradle file